# check each requested session in server js in node express 4 js

Tags: node.js

I m new in NODE js. so just need to know can we check session in one place rather than applying checks at each method.

This is possible to use single check at server.js for session management.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of express middleware

```
app.use( function(req, res, next) {

// req.session   #use this object

next();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

make it into a global middleware function

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.session.user.email }, function(err, user) {
      if (user) {
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.password; 
        req.session.user = user;  
        res.locals.user = user;
      }

      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```